# Discrete bins using cut()

Tags: r, dataframe, lattice

I want to plot the data [using lattice's xyplot()] in my dataframe age.model, based on discrete bins of the column StartAge.

I am using the following code:

```
# set up boundaries for intervals/bins
breaks <- c(0,3,4,5,6,8,13,15,17,18,19,20,22)
# specify interval/bin labels
labels <- c("<3", "3-4)", "4-5)","5-6)", "6-8)","8-13)", "13-15)","15-17)","17-18)","18-19)","19-20)",">=20")
# bucketing data points into bins
bins <- cut(age.model$StartAge, breaks, include.lowest = T, right=FALSE, labels=labels)
# inspect bins
summary(bins)
```

In cut()'s first argument, I have specified the column by which I want to discretize. However, the factor that is returned does not include the whole DF. How can I do this?

Reproducible using dput:

```
structure(list(Height = c(0.207224416925809, -1.19429150954007, 
0.0247585682642494, 0.023546515879641, 1.51423735121426, -1.09376538778425, 
-0.125209484617016, -0.63639210765747, 0.305071992864995, -0.422021082477656
), Weight = c(-0.366133564723644, -1.06969961340686, -0.0793604259237282, 
-0.708230200986797, 1.71593234004357, -0.685215310472794, -1.20353653394014, 
-0.490399232488568, 0.742874184424376, -0.331519044995803), Training = c(19, 
27, 27, 24, 35, 23, 15, 14, 47, 7), StartAge = c(13, 19, 20, 
20, 14, 2, 8, 4, 17, 18)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please provide a part of `age.model` to give us a reproducible example, using `dput` for example

Comment: Added, hope that helps?

Comment: From what I have understood, you can get the full dataframe with `age.model$bins <- bins`. Please provide expected output otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `xyplot` to **explore** your data, consider using `equal.count()` or `shingle()` in your code. Having (clueless) fun with your data, the approximate linear relationship between weight and height appears to not hold for the lower `StartAge` bins as show in the first example.

```
# Starting with data in age.model
  library(lattice)
  xyplot(Weight ~ Height | equal.count(StartAge), age.model, type = c("p", "r"))
```

The default number of bins for `equal.count` is 6. It can be changed easily to explore other groupings:

```
# Create four groups of equal counts to explore
  xyplot(Weight ~ Height | equal.count(StartAge, 4), age.model, type = c("p", "r"))
```

The `shingle()` function allows for overlapping bins as shown here.

```
# Create three groups that overlapping with each other 
  bins <- cbind(lower = c(0,8,16), upper = c(13,18,24))
  xyplot(Weight ~ Height | shingle(StartAge, bins), age.model, type = c("p", "r"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add bins to the dataframe, just affect it in a new column :

```
age.model$bins <- bins
```